# I deleted files from my Linux box's /boot directory and now it won't boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I did that to save space.

Now I see

> GRUB loading, please wait ...
>   ERROR 15

when booting.

What can I do ?

`/boot` still has files corresponding to `2.6.32-27` version of the Kernel. But I deleted all others that did not have that string in `/boot`.

Comment: If you deleted the `/boot/grub` directory, then you lost your GRUB menu, and all its other files. You should be able to boot from a Live CD and copy the `/boot/grub` directory from a working system onto the damaged one.

Comment: You deleted files in /boot **to save space**? Do you know what you deleted? You may look at [this HOWTO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099) though.

Comment: Also, for the future, in order to save space, you should use the package management (e.g. Synaptic) to remove old versions of `linux-image` and not just delete some files at random.

Comment: Helpful suggestion... Don't be logged in as root in the future if you don't know what you are doing...

Comment: Deleted boot and now it won't boot? I wonder....

Comment: Thanks slhck, the wiki was useful! However I could not get my system to work after only following the instructions under LIve CD section. I got a grub prompt on boot up. THen I did the chroot instructions and it worked. Just wondering why I got the grub prompt on boot up.

Comment: @abc Because GRUP not only is in the file system, but also in the Master Boot Record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to cleaning up /boot, especially on an Ubuntu box, use the package manager to remove the kernels.  You've wiped out the bootloader that boots your system, now you get to rebuild it by hand, or else reinstall.  We'll go at it with the rebuild-by-hand method.

1. Boot your machine with an Ubuntu LiveCD.  Once booted, you'll need to mount the boot partition from your hard drive.
2. Copy the grub directory from /boot/grub on the LiveCD to the mounted boot partition
3. Edit the menu.lst in the mounted boot partition, and modify the first entry to point to the kernel you have left on the disk.

This may get you going.  Worst case, boot from the LiveCD, copy any data you need to a backup location and reinstall.  Moral of the story:  Use the package management included with your distribution to clean up your disk, and ALWAYS be careful as root.